# Android socket can't send sentence

Tags: android

I'm using an Android client to connect to a Python server.  here is my Android client code, which connects via mobile Samsung mini galaxy to the sever via Open socket using same  wireless IP address:

```
public void appendText(View view){
    Text.append( "\n  In chat ");

    try{
//  while (true)
    //{
    sentence=inputfld.getText().toString();
    String sentence1=("hohohoh");
    Text.append( "\n  DataStream creating");        
    outToServer.writeBytes(sentence);
    outToServer.writeBytes(sentence1);
    modifiedSentence = inFromServer.readLine(); 
    Text.append(modifiedSentence);
    inputfld.setText(null);

        }
        }
        catch(Exception modifiedsentence){
        Text.append("Exception");
    }


}


public void connect(View view){




                try {
                    String cmd=("My current location is: " );
                    clientSocket= new Socket("192.168.1.2",54628); 
                    Text.append( "\n created a socket");
                    outToServer = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
                    Text.append( "\n created a datastream");
                    inFromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
                    Text.append( "\n created a bufferReader");
                   Text.append( "\n created a socket");


                } catch (SocketException e) {

                     e.printStackTrace();
                    }

    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Error");
        }
       }
```

The problem now is that I can connect and I have button to send on action event for appendtext, but it didn't let me send using the mobile.  What is wrong in my code?

Comment: Please read over the StackOverflow FAQ to learn more about this site. People answer questions to be be helpful and to get points.  You have not accepted a single answer to any of your questions meaning you have not fully contributed to this site.  The result of that is that people are less likely to help you.

Comment: Also, your question is very vague.  What do you mean by "it didnt let me send will using the mobile what is wrong in my code ?"  What is your actual problem?

Comment: i cant send a string data from android to python sevre

Comment: Is there an exception involved?  A stack trace would help.  Are you doing this over Wifi or your cellular network?